# Ajax POST HTML form with elements array using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

My Form looks like this:

```
<form id="invite-form" method="post" action="" >
 <input type="text" name=friends[0][first_name] />
 <input type="text" name=friends[0][last_name] />
 <input type="text" name=friends[0][email] />

 <input type="text" name=friends[1][first_name] />
 <input type="text" name=friends[1][last_name] />
 <input type="text" name=friends[1][email] />

 <input type="text" name=friends[2][first_name] />
 <input type="text" name=friends[2][last_name] />
 <input type="text" name=friends[2][email] />

 <input type="submit" value="Invite" />
</form>
```

And here is my javascript code:

```
var friends = [];
    jQuery("#invite-form").serializeArray().map(function(x){friends[x.name] = x.value;});
    var formData = {
        'friends'    : JSON.stringify(friends),
        'action'   : 'invite-friends'
    };
    jQuery.ajax({
        type        : 'POST',
        url         : '/invitation.php',
        data        : formData,
        dataType    : 'json',
        encode      : true
    }).done(function(data){
        console.log(data);
        if(data.success == true){
        ...
```

It doesn't work properly and the list of friends is not POSTed properly. How do I convert this kind of form to json data properly? I want to be able to use this data as a regular array, as if it were a regular form POSTed. I'm able to get the data using php://input which needs to be parsed, but I can't access it with $_POST.

Comment: `friends[x.name] = x.value` You can't do that. `friends` is an array, not an object. You need `friends = {}`

Comment: Why are you stringifying JSON and then putting it inside another object? That makes no sense. Don't jumble two data formats together like that, it's likely to cause you confusion (and has done so, by the looks of it). You could just send this as one JSON object if that's was your intention. `formData = JSON.stringify({ 'friends' : (friends), 
 action' : 'invite-friends' });`. And ensure also that the `contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8"` option is set in the $.ajax properties, of course) and lastly read it correctly in PHP (google "how to receive json post php" for details)

Comment: "It doesn't work properly" - what does that mean? Is this a JS problem or a PHP problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase I mean, usually, I do $_POST in PHP to access POST data. But in this case, I've to use php://input to obtain the JSON data and parse it.

Answer (score 0):

> In this way you can submit form with serialize data and you many use
> post or get request for this or any other method.

```
jQuery("#invite-form").submit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   let data = jQuery(this).serialize();
    jQuery.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: 'invitation.php',
                data: data,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
 });
```

Comment: I get this in the POST data: 
friends[0][fname]=a&friends[0][lname]=a&friends[0][email]=a@test.com&friends[1][fname]=b&friends[1][lname]=b&friends[1][email]=b@test.com

How do I convert it back to an array in php?

Comment: I think you need to make post request and pass data in the request not in the url for this. If the variable name is same you will get array in php by using request.